# How to use chromecast from mac

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, chromecast

Chromecast has been installed on my os/x mavericks 10.9.1 and it is successfully transmitting images to the HDTV. In addition the Cast chrome extension is installed.

When we go to netflix or youtube where is the "cast" icon they talk about? Is there some additional step that is still required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast button is located in the browser extensions icons.

My Understanding is that you can open Netflix in Chrome and click the "Cast" button in the browser extensions list.  This will mirror it over to the Chromecast.

See the Help Guide [HERE](https://support.netflix.com/en/node/10377).

Answer (score 0):

Youtube app & youtube.com has a new cast icon at the bottom right corner next to fullscreen option. Hit that to stream from youtube app or youtube.com